# Wubi error installing - Extraction failed with code: 2

Tags: wubi

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu with Wubi after having a problem on my existing Wubi install which booted to a `GRUB>` prompt.

But now I have new problem:

> **Ubuntu Installer**

```
An error occured:
Extraction failed with code: 2
For more information, please see the log file:
c:\users\joseda~1.per\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev272.log
```

Here's the download to the log file:

> http://www.mediafire.com/?ozois9eeo6aa7ya

Comment: **If you're answering, please click button "Answer Question" and but don't help using the "Add Comment", if you use "Answer Question" i glad you are best at helpin' me =D**

Comment: **Uh Harddrive: (Currect Drive - 123/232 GB) C:/ | (Recovery Drive (Where i installed ubuntu because this has more space than the C:/) - 193 - 30 = 163/232 GB) D:/ | (IDK - 25.5/99.99 MB) H:/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the log, the diskimage file is `549666608` bytes, but it only downloaded `2728096` bytes. That's why the extraction failed. Try running it again and make sure your internet connection is good.

```
06-03 02:36 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=D:\ubuntu\disks\ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, 
url=http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.2/ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, 
basename=ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, length=549666608, text=None
06-03 02:53 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 2728096 bytes)
06-03 02:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
06-03 02:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished get_diskimage
06-03 02:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_diskimage...
06-03 02:54 ERROR  TaskList: Extraction failed with code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some Googling and according to [this website](https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/181794) it is a bug with Wubi and the user suggested "rebooting to see if it was successful. Then add a comment to the bug report for your situation if the install boot successfully.". If this fails try doing the proper install of Ubuntu (burning the .iso of the version to a disk/USB drive and installing it from there). This would usually be better than a Wubi install anyway as it would generally operate faster (from personal experience). I hope this has helped you in some way :)

Comment: **I'll try it and i'll comment you back if the Problem is fixed/solved or this still happens.**

Comment: From now on I will mark it as an answer, I'll have to get used to this website ha. So are you still stuck with the problem? I am not too sure of your problem's status from your last comment which was listing your HDD's space.